# Javascript: How can every set of numbers in an array be extracted?

Tags: csv, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a csv file output in this format
[image]

that correspond the values of this firebase DB.
[image]

what I want to do is run each ID through firebase DB to find a match.

strategy

Read csv file data 
   Omit the word ID and extract every 8 numbers (which is the length of the ID numbers) 
   Run the extracted ID values through firebase to find match and print snapshot.

this is the function that generates the file readout
        var IDArr = [];

```
      var fileInput = document.getElementById("csv");

      readFile = function () {

              console.log("file uploaded")
              var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = function () {
      reader.readAsBinaryString(fileInput.files[0]);
          };

           if (fileInput){
                fileInput.addEventListener('change', readFile);
      }
```

How do I implement the strategy above? A sample code will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use a `for` loop?

Comment: @sircodesalot how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out the answer.

```
  for (var i=0; i < numbers.length; i++) {

                    var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Agents').child(numbers[i]);

                       dbRef.on('value', snapshot => {
                          console.log(snapshot.val());
                        });

                        alert(numbers[i]);
                      }
```